# How to work with context in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to create a confirmation page. `User` can create orders on one page, then the `create_order` view validates the `forms` and send a request with context to another `view` which is called `confirm_order`. I think that I would work correct but there is one problem. The first time `confirm_order` gets `request` and `context` which contains data from `forms`. But when `User` clicks on confirm in this page, the `confirm_view` is called without this context so I'm getting error:

> ```
> > ValidationError at /create-job/ [u'ManagementForm data is missing or
> > has been tampered with']
> ```

Do you guys know how to send the context second time?

Here are those two views:

```
def create_order(request):
    LanguageLevelFormSet = formset_factory(LanguageLevelForm, extra=5, max_num=5)
    language_level_formset = LanguageLevelFormSet(request.POST or None)
    job_creation_form = JobCreationForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

    context = {'job_creation_form': job_creation_form,
               'formset': language_level_formset}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if job_creation_form.is_valid() and language_level_formset.is_valid():
            cleaned_data_job_creation_form = job_creation_form.cleaned_data
            cleaned_data_language_level_formset = language_level_formset.cleaned_data

            context = {
                'cleaned_data_job_creation_form': cleaned_data_job_creation_form,
                "cleaned_data_language_level_formset": cleaned_data_language_level_formset,
            }
            mutable = request.POST._mutable # I'm adding parameter 'review' to be able to differ between two different posts in confirm_order view
            request.POST._mutable = True
            request.POST['review'] = True
            request.POST._mutable = mutable
            return confirm_order(request, context)
        else:
            return render(request, 'auth/jobs/create-job.html', context=context)
    return render(request, 'auth/jobs/create-job.html', context=context)


def confirm_order(request, context):
    print context
    cleaned_data_job_creation_form = context['cleaned_data_job_creation_form']
    cleaned_data_language_level_formset = context['cleaned_data_language_level_formset']
    print request.POST['review']
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['review'] == True:

        file = cleaned_data_job_creation_form['file']
        count = 5 #simplified multiple rows
        jobs = []
        for language_level_form in [d for d in cleaned_data_language_level_formset if d]:
            language = language_level_form['language']
            level = language_level_form['level']
            d = {}
            d['language_from'] = cleaned_data_job_creation_form['language_from'].name
            d['language_to'] = language
            d['number_of_characters'] = count
            d['price_per_sign'] = 1
            d['estimated_price'] = count * d['price_per_sign']
            jobs.append(d)

        table = CreatedOrdersTable(jobs)
        context = {'table': table,
                   'cleaned_data_job_creation_form': cleaned_data_job_creation_form,
                   'cleaned_data_language_level_formset': cleaned_data_language_level_formset}
        return render(request, 'auth/jobs/confirm-order.html', context=context)
    else:
        for language_level_form in [d for d in cleaned_data_language_level_formset if d]:
            language = language_level_form['language']
            level = language_level_form['level']

            Job.objects.create(
                    customer=request.user,
                    text_to_translate=cleaned_data_job_creation_form['text_to_translate'],
                    file=cleaned_data_job_creation_form['file'],
                    short_description=cleaned_data_job_creation_form['short_description'],
                    notes=cleaned_data_job_creation_form['notes'],
                    language_from=cleaned_data_job_creation_form['language_from'],
                    language_to=language,
                    level=level,
            )
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/order-success')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a template render on your first view. So, the request doesn't end on your confirm_order view.

If you want, you can redirect to reverse('confirm_order') and add the data on session.

In your confirm_order view you will pop the data from session and continue with your flow.

Comment: Thanks and could you elaborate how to send session?

Comment: In create_order() you can do something like this: request.session['cleaned_data_job_creation_form'] = cleaned_data_job_creation_form . After you redirect to confirm_order() you can get access to the form like this: request.session.pop('cleaned_data_job_creation_form')

Comment: Thanks, but there is a big problem. The cleaned_data contains models objects and I can't just send it this way, moreover I can't even serialize it.